# validation csv file rails using heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got a such task (I have to use heroku):

I need get file from user computer (CSV file), validate this file and generate a PDF report.

I don't know which flow should be:

1. Upload file to S3, then download file into a local temp folder, parse and validate file and next send it to S3
2. Put a file to tmp folder, validate and then send to S3 server.

or another solution?